Why can I not use a protocol in Swift as a generic parameter which needs to conform to another protocol?
Simple example:
actor Storage<V: Hashable> {
    let value: V
    
    init(value: V) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

protocol Labelled: Hashable {
    var label: String { get }
}

let storage: Storage<Labelled> // Doesn't compile (Swift 6.0.2): "Type 'any Labelled' cannot conform to 'Hashable'"

What am I missing? This looks super basic. Obviously any type that conforms to Labelled needs to conform to Hashable, too?
Edit: whoever marked this as a duplicate question of Protocol doesn't conform to itself? – how is this related to the question of whether a protocol confirms to itself?!
Edit: Note that the following DOES compile:
actor Storage<V> { // <-- requirement of conforming to `Hashable` dropped
    let value: V
    
    init(value: V) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

protocol Labelled: Hashable {
    var label: String { get }
}

let storage: Storage<any Labelled> // Note: compiler wants me to add `any` here


It means, the Swift compiler cannot take an existential any Labelled as an argument for the parameter value in the initialiser of Storage, and opens this existential, in order to get the contained value with the actual type conforming to Hashable. In other words, you need to specify a concrete type for the generic parameter for Storage. You might use AnyHashable or any concrete type that conforms to Hashable as the type parameter instead of Labelled.

@CouchDeveloper please consider my edit / addition which shows that I can in fact use any Labelled as a generic parameter.

Yes, but now Storage doesn't know anymore, that V conforms to Hashable.  That means, you can't have a member var of type Dictionary<Key, Value> for example, where Key is V, since Key needs to conform to Hashable. Note also, that the initialiser (aka init(value: V) where V: Hashable also changed to init(value: V).

Sure. That's my problem though and not the compiler's. I still don't have an answer to my original question: why I can't have the additional constraint of V (in my example) having to conform to Hashable (or any other protocol).

The reason is, that the initialiser of your generic Storage gets passed in an any Value, where any Value is actually some kind of box, capable to carry many different kinds of type Value. The initialiser needs to initialise a value of concrete type denoted with type parameter Value. This value is inside the "box" (any Value) and Storage needs to know its concrete type. However, Swift is unable to "unbox" this any Value container and extract the actual value, because it does not know the concrete type.
